# Showing water filling inside of a specific map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show water filling gradually inside of Karnataka map using javaScript and JQuery. It should have maximum value and minimum value and should compute everything in percentage. For eg: if the max value is 300 and min value is 60 it should start computing and fill water only till 20% of the map (60/300 * 100). How to do it using JQuery. I have done it for a simple circle and the code is as below.

```js
let total = document.querySelector("input[id=total]");
let correct = document.querySelector("input[id=correct]");
let getPercentage = document.querySelector("button");
let score = document.querySelector("div[id=score]");
let p_value = document.querySelector("p[id=value]");
let content = document.querySelector("span");
getPercentage.onclick = (evt) => {
    let percentage = (parseInt(correct.value)/parseInt(total.value))*100;
    p_value.innerHTML = Math.floor(percentage)+"%";
    var  white_per=  100 - percentage ;
    score.style.background = 'linear-gradient(0deg,green ' + percentage +'%,white ' + percentage + '%)';
}
```

```css
#main{
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: 200px 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border:18px solid darkgrey;
  /* display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  */
}

#score{ 
  position : absolute;
  height : 100%;
  width : 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background : linear-gradient(0deg, lightblue 75%,white 25% );
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="score">
    <p id="value"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="position:relative;top:20px;">
  Enter TotalMarks              : <input id="total" type="text"/></br>
  Enter CorrectAnswer Marks     : <input id="correct" type="text"/></br>
  <button>getPercentage</button>
<div>
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your question? Your code works.

Comment: In the same code I want to replace circle with a Karnataka map. And if I add values in the text boxes it should fill with green colors

Comment: I am still unable to figure out how to do it. Please help..